# How to fix "Issue found: Families Data Practices"

Tags: android-studio, console, google-play, android-permissions

Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies

Issue found: Families Data Practices
We’ve identified that your app or an SDK in your app transmits device identifier(s) from children or users of unknown age that do not comply with our Families Policy.

These identifiers may include but are not limited to Advertising ID.
Your app may face additional enforcement actions, if you do not resolve this issue by April 26, 2023.
Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Code Analysis
About the Families Policy Requirements
Apps that solely target children should not transmit the following:

Android Advertising ID (AAID)
SIM Serial
Build Serial
BSSID
MAC
SSID
IMEI and/or IMSI
Apps that target both children and older audiences must not transmit the listed identifiers from children or users of unknown age.

How to fix "Issue found: Families Data Practices

Comment: Hi @mahumid, did you fix the problem? I have tried everything including change age group to above 18, and add AD_ID permission. but Google Play still think our app violates their family data practice.

Answer (score 1):

add this permission to manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>`

Answer (score 1):

I added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>`
to the Android Manifest xml as in the other answer, and I also added this other code

```html
private void Start()
     {
     RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = new RequestConfiguration
    {
        TagForChildDirectedTreatment = TagForChildDirectedTreatment.True,
        MaxAdContentRating = MaxAdContentRating.G
    };
    MobileAds.SetRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);
     }
```

as explained on the website itself. Google Admob Mobile Ads SDK (Unity)

- https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/targeting?hl=en

my game is for all ages

Answer (score 0):

issue found: Families Data Practices We’ve identified that your app or an SDK in your app transmits device identifier(s) from children or users of unknown age that do not comply with our Families Policy.

- Remove the AAID permision

Answer (score 0):

In my Unity Ads settings side:

- Game-level age designation => This app is directed to children as defined by applicable laws.
- Is this a Mixed Audience game? => Yes
- Google Designed for Families => Enabled

In Google Play Console side:

- Advertising Id => Yes and for Advertising and Marketing.

In Unity Editor side:

- I kept the Android Manifest xml file as it is and did not modify anything. Unity SDK already included the AAID in it, so we (developers) do not need to include it in the Android Manifest file.
- Build another bundle version and submit to Google for another review.

Got approved!